# How to get dialog to overlay the MainActiviy of the app

Tags: android-intent, dialog, themes

So, here's an interesting problem.

I use intents to jump from one activity to another in my app. For instance:

...

```
private fun onAddNewBird() {
    activityMainBinding!!.fabAddBird.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AddBirdActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        this.finish()
    }
}
```

...

This works like a charm.

I wanted to open this activity as a dialog, following Android Documentation recommendations.

The problem is that the dialog overlays the home page of the emulator instead of overlaying the MainActivity of the app.

Android Documentation says:

"If you want a custom dialog, you can instead display an Activity as a dialog instead of using the Dialog APIs. Create an activity and set its theme to Theme.Holo.Dialog in the  manifest element:"

When I used the Theme.Holo.Dialog theme I got the following error:

"View class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)."

So I replaced Theme.Holo.Dialog with Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog. The Manifest looks like this:

...

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.WBS"
    tools:targetApi="31">

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wbs.ui.activity.AddBirdActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wbs.ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

...

This opens the AddBirdActivity as a dialog which overlays the home page of the emulator instead of overlaying the MainActivity of the app.

Why is this happening and how do I get the dialog to overlay the MainActivity of the app?

Thanks, littltoldlady